# Custom input function for estimator instead of tf.data.dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I want to know if anyone has created their own custom input function for tensorflow's estimator ? like in ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/premade_estimators#create_input_functions)) this image:[image]

where the say it is recommended to use tf.data.dataset. But I do not want to use that one, as I want to write my own iterator which yields data in batches and shuffles it as well.

```
    def data_in(train_data):
      data = next(train_data)
      ff = list(data)
      tf.enable_eager_execution()
      imgs = tf.stack([tf.convert_to_tensor(np.reshape(f[0], [img_size[0], img_size[1], img_size[2]])) for f
                                        in ff])
      lbls = tf.stack([f[1] for f in ff])
      print('TRAIN data: %s %s ' % (imgs.get_shape(), lbls.get_shape()))
      return imgs, lbls
```

output: `TRAIN data: (10, 32, 32, 3) (10,)`

where train_data is a generator object which iterates through my dataset using **iter** and np.reshape(f[0], [img_size[0], img_size[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKynA.png), img_size[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKynA.png)] basically reshapes the data I extract to the required dimensions and it is a batch of an entire dataset. I use stack to convert the list of tensors to convert to stacked tensors. But when I use this with estimators I get an error for the features provided to the model saying the features do not have get_shape(). When I test it without an estimator it works well and it get_shape() also works well.

Comment: the example documentation you shared does not actually demonstrate how to use that function. Perhaps you may need to wrap your function with the [numpy_input_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn) before feeding to the estimator?

Comment: hi kvish thank you for your response :). well the data I get for imgs and lbls they are already in batches, so using numpy_input_fn is not useful for me. As it takes the entire dataset and then reads batches from it.

Answer (score 1):

Hey kvish I figured it out how to do it. I just had to add these lines

```
experiment = tf.contrib.learn.Experiment(
cifar_classifier,
train_input_fn=lambda: data_in(),
eval_input_fn=lambda: data_in_eval(),
train_steps=train_steps)
```

I know experiment is deprecated, I will also do it with estimator now :)

Comment: that is good. I wish they had better documentation. Especially for customizing the Estimator pipelines!

Comment: i checked it out further today and unfortunately it is not working the way I intended it to. the tf.estimator.trainandevaluate() calls the training once. I am not sure if the estimator is calling the train_input_fn after every batch. Do you know any way if I can check if different batches are being loaded or not ? (Usually during training my GPU is always loaded with data)

Comment: I just checked the source code for the estimator and referred some of the documentation there. 
"Calling methods of `Estimator` will work while eager execution is enabled.
  However, the `model_fn` and `input_fn` is not executed eagerly. `Estimator` will switch to graph model before calling all user-provided functions (incl. hooks), so their code has to be compatible with graph mode execution.Note
  that `input_fn` code using `tf.data` generally works in both graph and eager
  modes"
You are doing eager execution inside the function as far as I can see, so maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Hey @kvish thank you for the response, I tried it without eager execution as well. But it is still not going on the the next batch. I guess it requires graph to be built during the data reading and I am not doing that as estimators are high-level APIs and give no access to the graphs to the users.

Comment: i read the paper about Estimators and they have mentioned in it that I cannot access the graph and also the iterator from tf use the graphs. So in short I am compelled to use tf.data class and nothing else.

Comment: have you checked if anyone has raised github issues with the team about the same requirement? It kind of seems irresponsible to suggest you can do something in the example documentation and then make it really difficult to figure out how to do it right!

Comment: after some more digging probably the reason is because the input_fn as such is called only once. [Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43768063/10111931)

Comment: Hey kvish thank you for the pointer, I had seen this one earlier as well :) in this one, the generator needs to yield only one sample of data at a time. Whereas, my generator class yields an entire batch at a time. So I have to use their way :P thank you for sparing your time and efforts for this question. I really appreciate it.

Comment: sure. I think your problems would be better solved using the dataset api here so that you dont end up wasting lot of time and effort with limited support!

Comment: yes, true actually I did that as well :) i just wanted to try with custom input if it is possible to do what I intended to but now I am going back to use the APIs itself :) Thank you kvish